# Apply text syle to a regex pattern in google sheet cells

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, textstyle

I would like to get parts of strings (by regex) into a specific text style, but I can't manage the loop. I always get errors.

In the first row is the original text (strings separated by commas), and in the second under, is the desired text style.
[image]

Here is the sheet (french parameters) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vq0Ai_wEr3MamEQ-kMsXW7ZGg3RxrrkE5lITcYjO-rU/edit?usp=sharing

```
function NomsStyleBotanique(){
  const classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();  // var Feuille = classeur.getSheetByName('Feuille 1'); 
  var ligne = classeur.getCurrentCell().getRow();
  var colonne = classeur.getCurrentCell().getColumn();
  var range = classeur.getActiveRange();

  var richTextValues = range.getRichTextValues().map(([a]) => {
  var text = a.getText();
  var pos = 0;
  
  var myregEx = /,/g;
  var Noms = text.split(myregEx);
  
  var textStyleNomPlante = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
        .setFontSize(10)
        .setForegroundColor("black")
        .setFontFamily("Times New Roman")
        .setItalic(false)
        .build();

    var textStyleNomAuteur = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
        .setFontSize(10)
        .setForegroundColor("#616399")     // ("grey")
        .setFontFamily("Times New Roman")
        .setItalic(true)
        .build();

  var nbPhrases = [];
  var i =0;
 
  while (Noms){ i++; nbPhrases.push(Noms[i]); // SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(Noms[i]); 
  
  for (var i=0;i<nbPhrases.length;i++){
  
  var myarr = Noms[i].split(" ");
  var Espace1 = myarr[0].length+1;
  var Espace2 = myarr[1].length+1;

  if (Noms[i]){
    if ((Noms[i].indexOf("subsp") > 1) || (Noms[i].indexOf("var.") > 1)){
    var Espace3 = myarr[2].length+1;
    var Espace4 = myarr[3].length+1;
    pos = Espace1+Espace2+Espace3+Espace4; }

  else {   pos = Espace1+Espace2;  } // pos = text.match(new RegExp(/\\s/, 'g'))[2]; 

  var position = pos;

  if (position > -1){
      var temp = a.getTextStyle(0, position - 1);

    return [
        SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
        .setText(Noms[i])
        .setTextStyle(0, position - 1, textStyleNomPlante)
        .setTextStyle(position, Noms[i].length, textStyleNomAuteur)
        .build()
      ];
    }
    return [SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(Noms[i]).setTextStyle(Noms[i].getTextStyle()).build()];
   }
  }
 }
} // fin boucle
);
range.setRichTextValues(richTextValues);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your sample image. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Sorry for not being so clear as expected. In the first row is the original text, and in the second under, is the desired text style. It is about botanical names separated by commas, and I want to put in color the authors' names. In the second row, the red text in third position shows a difficulty to match the authors names, but it doesn't matter because it doesn't often happen, I can at least treat it manually

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. I have a question. When I saw the value of `Desired style`, I cannot understand about the logic that `(Griseb.) Briq` is not red font color. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of the logic for achieving your goal?

Comment: Oups, very sorry !! it is now corrected

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand about the logic for achieving your goal. I apologize for my poor understanding. Can I ask you about the detail of the logic for achieving your goal?

Comment: In cells, are strings (botanical names) separated by commas. Each botanical name is composed by a 1st word for the Genus, a 2nd word for the Specie, sometimes a 3rd word indicates 'subsp.' or 'var.' and in that case a 4th word indicates that subspecie (or var) name, and authors' name. So at least each botanical name is a variable string composed by 2 or 4 words followed by x words indicating human names (ex. (Griseb.) Briq). So in all that strings (botanical names) separated by commas, I want to apply a style text (bold, red or whatever) to thir last part (human names)

Comment: Conclusion : in the cells I have strings separated by commas. Each string = 2 or 4 words + n words. I want to change the text style of the n last words in each string

Comment: If the beginning of a string has 4 words, the 3rd word is always 'subsp.' or 'var.'

Comment: Hi @Nad, the problem here is that you have the author names sometimes separated by a comma and sometimes the author names are not separated by a comma. See `Ten., Benth., Swart,`  vs. `(Ten.) Kerguélen`. Your code does not account for this. I don't know if there is a way to create a pattern to recognize the break between plants names vs. the break between author names. I would need to see more of your data to determine if there are other patterns we could use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Adam, I don't think there's any solution to that point, there is no other characters to base on for a regex. But it doesn't often happen, so at least I can treat it manually. However, I have added some more lines to the sheet so that you can fully realise

Comment: My main problem is the loop I can't handle

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that your issue had been resolved. I'm glad for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem here is that the author names are sometimes separated by a comma and sometimes separated by just a space. See `Ten., Benth., Swart,` and `(Ten.) Kerguélen`. However, in your comment, you said this does not happen often though and that you could just deal with this manually, so let's just assume for now that author names are never separated commas.

With the assumption, we can split the contents of each cell by `,`  and deal with each plant name/author separately:

```js
const plants = text.split(', ')

for (const plant of plants) {
  // Find start/end of authors substring.
}
```

What we need is to find the indices where the "plant author" substring starts and ends.

Finding the end index of the plant author substring is easy; it's just the end of the entire plant string:

```js
const end = plant.length
```

To find the start of the plant author substring, we can look for the indices of the spaces `' '`. (You'll need to write your own `getIndices()` method for this.) If the plant contains `subsp.` or `var.`, the start index is the 4th space; otherwise, it is the 2nd space:

```js
let start
spaceIndices = getIndices(plant, ' ')
if (plant.includes('subsp.') || plant.includes('var.')) start = spaceIndices[3] + 1  // Add 1 to not include the space itself
else start = spaceIndices[1] + 1  // Add 1 to not include the space itself
```

Once we have the start/end indices, we can put them in an array `offsets` that we will use to find the `startOffset` and `endOffset` values for the `setTextStyle()` method.

So now we have:

```js
const plants = text.split(', ')
let offsets = []
for (const plant of plants) {
  const end = plant.length
  
  let start
  spaceIndices = getIndices(plant, ' ')
  if (plant.includes('subsp.') || plant.includes('var.')) start = spaceIndices[3] + 1
  else start = spaceIndices[1] + 1

  offsets.push({
    start,
    end
  })
}
```

Next, we have to initiate the `RichTextValueBuilder` object and loop through the `offsets` array to determine what the `startOffset` and `endOffset` values should be for the `setTextStyles()` method by adding where `start` and `end` values we found earlier to index

```js
let richText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
  .setText(text)
let authorTextStyle = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
  .setBold(true)
  .build()

let plantStartIndex = 0
for (const offset of offsets) {
  const startOffset = plantStartIndex + offset.start
  const endOffset = plantStartIndex + offset.end
  richText = richText.setTextStyle(startOffset, endOffset, authorTextStyle)
  plantStartIndex = plantStartIndex + offset.end + 2  // Add 2 to not include the ", " separator
}
```

Finally, build the `RichTextValue` object:

```js
richText = richText.build()
```

…and tie it all together with the rest of your code:

```js
function stylePlantNames() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  const range = ss.getActiveRange()
  const values = range.getValues()

  let richTextValues = []

  for (const row of values) {
    let text = row[0]

    const plants = text.split(', ')

    let offsets = []
    for (const plant of plants) {
      const end = plant.length

      let start
      spaceIndices = getIndices(plant, ' ')
      if (plant.includes('subsp.') || plant.includes('var.')) start = spaceIndices[3] + 1
      else start = spaceIndices[1] + 1

      offsets.push({
        start,
        end
      })
    }

    let richText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
      .setText(text)
    let authorTextStyle = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
      .setBold(true)
      .build()

    let plantStartIndex = 0
    for (const offset of offsets) {
      const startOffset = plantStartIndex + offset.start
      const endOffset = plantStartIndex + offset.end
      richText = richText.setTextStyle(startOffset, endOffset, authorTextStyle)
      plantStartIndex = plantStartIndex + offset.end + 2
    }

    richText = richText.build()
    richTextValues.push([richText])

  }

  range.setRichTextValues(richTextValues)

}

function getIndices(str, char) {
  let indices = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] === char) indices.push(i);
  }
  return indices;
}
```

I skipped over many details of how the Apps Script APIs work for spreadsheets and rich text formatting. You'll need to set your own styles, but from your code, it seems like you already know how to do this. The tricky part of your question is figuring out how to identify the author substring, so that's what I focused on for my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much @Adam, you have perfectly understood what I needed !! I was getting mad with that .map loop and reading some old stackoverflow posts I was not sure it could be achieved. Life bless you, I can now save hours of typing, and you also taught me some other functions I didn't even knew :-)